# Set property in DataContext object through xaml

Tags: .net, xaml, mvvm

Suppose I have the following xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MainView" ...>
    :
    <my:ChildView />
    :
</UserControl>
```

When ChildView is instantiated, it automatically creates an object of type ChildViewModel and attaches it to its DataContext. ChildViewModel has a property "Abc".

MainView has a backing MainViewModel object as its DataContext. MainViewModel has also a property "Def".

Is there any way through xaml to send the value in the property MainViewModel.Def to ChildViewModel.Abc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

communication between viewmodels is done via messenger/mediator or eventaggregator. you dont have to go a way "through xaml"

EDIT: because i like viewmodel frist - i do this in my projects

the mainviewmodel holds an instance of the childviewmodel. the ChildView do not create a ChildViewmodel anymore.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MainView" ...>
  <UserControl.Resources>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ChildViewmodel}">
    <my:ChildView />
   </DataTemplate>
  </UserControl.Resources>
 :
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyChildView"} />
  :
</UserControl>
```

no i can simply set the Def property value to the childviewmodel because i have the instance in my mainviewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

If its like a parent child view, Child view should not create the Viewmodel itself, instead create that childviewmodel as a property of the main viewmodel and the set the datacontext of the child view as below. Now the main viewmodel will have access to the properties of the child viewmodel

```
<UserControl x:Class="MainView" ...>
:
<my:ChildView DataContext{Binding ChildViewModelProperty}/>
:
</UserControl>
```